# The API returned an error: Error: No access or refresh token is set

Tags: google-classroom

I was able to successfully log in using Google Classroom and pull the course data during the trial. This was on my local machine. Now I have moved to my test server. I can still log in via google but can no longer pull the course data. I have already updated my client_secret file (updated the appropriate endpoints) but i get the following error after calling `classroom.courses.list`

Error: No access or refresh token is set.

Would appreciate anyone's help. I do have Google Classroom API as one of my APIs. Not sure if it's because i'm now on a domain instead of my localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I was doing a 2 part registration. The first past, I was setting the token. When the page was submitted again with new details from the user, when I was making the call to google, I hadn't set the token.